# Holoviews - How to create side-by-side bars from dataframe columns?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot

I would like to create a Holoviews bar chart (using Bokeh backend) in which Year is on the X-axis and columns A and B on the Y-Axis. For each Year, I want bars for values from columns A and B to appear next to each other i.e. for Year 2008, I have bars of heights 1 and 3, for year 2009, I have bars 3 and 6 height, and so on. I have tried numerous different ways including the example of [grouped bars](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Bars.html) in the documentation but can't get it to work. See example below:

```
%%opts Bars [xrotation=90 width=600 show_legend=False tools=['hover']]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013],
   'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[3,6,9,12,15,18]})
print(df)
bars = hv.Bars(df, kdims=['Year'], vdims=['A'])
bars
```

Please help. I am losing my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HoloViews generally works best when your data is in what's called a tidy format. However to make it easier to work with data like yours we have developed a companion library called [hvPlot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/). To generate the plot you want you can simply run:

```
import hvplot.pandas
df=pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013],
   'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[3,6,9,12,15,18]})
df.hvplot.bar('Year')
```

[image]

Alternatively you can learn about the pd.melt method, which can take your data in a wide format and convert it to a tidy dataset:

```
%%opts Bars [xrotation=90 width=600 show_legend=False tools=['hover']]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013],
   'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[3,6,9,12,15,18]})
tidy_df = df.melt(id_vars=['Year'], value_vars=['A', 'B'])
bars = hv.Bars(tidy_df, ['Year', 'variable'], ['value'])
bars
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well! Didn't know about hvplot! A followup, do you know if there is a way to suppress printing 'A' and 'B' on the x-axis so I can make it less cluttered? I plan to have a legend instead.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to [@pongo30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7695113/pongo30) you can suppress printing 'A' and 'B' on the x-axis by adding `.opts(xlabel='')` to the call to `hvplot.bar()` (ex: `df.hvplot.bar('Year').opts(xlabel='')`)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.opts(multi_level=False)
```

E.g.

```
df.hvplot.bar('Year').opts(multi_level=False)
```